# countouring two xyz files

Tags: math, r, geospatial, gis

i have two spatial xyz file with different resolution
 how can i contour a composition of both files
i like working with R or open source geographical systems like GMT
 if u know of a different way of solving this i would be glad to listen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it!!
i used GMT (generic mapping tools)

> surface roads -Groads.grd -I0.002/0.002 -N8 -R34.66636708/34.87547842/31.64851241/31.82722429 -S0.002
>   grdcontour roads.grd -Cconc.cpt -JM15c>roads.ps

i did the same for both xyz files so i got the sam grid